# Whitelist specific query from hibernate slow query logging

Tags: java, hibernate, logging

I am using below hibernate settings to log slow queries for my application
`hibernate.session.events.log.LOG_QUERIES_SLOWER_THAN_MS : <time>`
`org.hibernate.SQL_SLOW: warn`

It is working fine. But I want to whitelist a few queries so that even if they run beyond 'LOG_QUERIES_SLOWER_THAN_MS' will not be logged as a warning. I want to do that as I know there are a few queries which supposed to take a longer time to run and I don't want to generate any alerts for those.

Is there any way I can do that?

I have tried to find any settings I can provide during the query to override the behaviour for that specific query.

Are there any settings and API hibernate provide to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that with plain Hibernate. You can just disable the `org.hibernate.SQL_SLOW` logger temporarily with your logger API by setting the level programatically to e.g. WARN and then reset it again to INFO.